# I want #tabulator to show loader when data is loading and throw error when no data is available

Tags: javascript, tabulator

I am using the latest version 5.0 so i am using the dataloaders instaed of ajax but still not working, i am fetching data from a database using `meteor.call()`

```
height: "100%",
dataLoader: true,
dataLoaderLoading:"<div style='display:inline-block; border:4px solid #333; border-radius:10px; background:#fff; font-weight:bold; font-size:16px; color:#000; padding:10px 20px;'>Loading Data</div>",
dataLoaderError: "<div style='display:inline-block; border:4px solid #D00; border-radius:10px; background:#fff; font-weight:bold; font-size:16px; color:#590000; padding:10px 20px;'>Loading Error</div>",
data: this.selector.get(),
layout: "fitColumns", 
placeholder: "No Data Available",
```

Answer (score 0):

Tabulator does not consider it to be an error when the table is empty, this is a perfectly valid state for the table.

In order to do this you would need to override the ajax request promise function using the `ajaxRequestFunc` property, and the return a promise that resolves the data if the request is successfull and has data, and rejects if the request fails or there is no data.

For full details checkout the [Overriding the Ajax Request Promise Documentation](http://tabulator.info/docs/5.1/data#ajax-promise)